# solving union and intersection of family of sets problem using number line?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

though I don't even know high school math properly(I only know about some grade 10 level set-theory,polynomial math knowledge because I didn't study hard...) but I tried to read herstein's "Topics in algebra" just for fun and in the book there is a problem like this:

> For instance, if $S$  is the set of real numbers, and if $T$ is the set of rational
> numbers, let, for $\alpha \in T, \ A_{\alpha}= \{x\in S\ | \ x\ge\alpha\}$. It is an easy exercise to see that $\cup_{\alpha\in T}A_{\alpha}=S$ whereas $\cap_{\alpha\in T}A_{\alpha}$ is the null set. The sets $A_{\alpha}$ are not mutually disjoint.

I roughly thought like this:

When I imagine a point $\alpha$ on the number line such that $A_{\alpha}= \{x\in S\ | \ x\ge\alpha\}$,

The smaller the size of $\alpha$, the more it goes to the left, the larger the size of $\alpha$, the more it goes to the right.

So, if the point $\alpha$ is gradually moved to the leftmost on the number line, eventually the interval of point $\alpha$ (the entire interval to the right of $\alpha$) becomes the entire rational number. and since $x≥\alpha$ is the condition, irrational numbers between rational numbers are included.

So ∪(a∈T)Aα = S

If I move the point a to the rightmost, there is no overlapping interval, so $\cap_{\alpha\in T}A_{\alpha}$ is the null set.

And I thought the reason why The sets $A_{\alpha}$ are not mutually disjoint is because even though there are no elements common to "all" sets in a family of sets, but "some" sets have elements in common with each other.

I know this is not formal proof at all, but is this right ideas?

And If I study high school math properly or furthermore if I study the prerequisites step by step, will i be able to understand this book easily?
Or is this book actually requiring little background knowledge, and the reason I find it difficult is simply my lack of understanding ability?

Should I just be interested in physics or programming rather than rigorous mathematics?(Actually Math is just a hobby for me by the way. I am considering becoming a programmer. the reason I want to study (undergraduate) mathematics is because of the programming applicability of algebra, combinatorics, analysis and because of my curiosity.)

Comment: Hi! Usually, minus infinity on the number line is pictured at the left. Therefore, paraphrasing your post, the smaller the size of $\alpha$, the more it goes to the *left* (and vice-versa). The set $A_\alpha$ contains real numbers that are bigger or equal to $\alpha$, so the smaller the size of $\alpha$, the more "area" it takes on the number line. It seems to me you've written the opposite.

Comment: Obviously my comment is immaterial if you picture your number line with minus infinity at the right...

Comment: @Marc-André Brochu Oh, I'm sorry I will fix it immediately! Thank you for pointing out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right ideas. Here's a more formal proof, in my case it is coming from the same intuition you described in your post. Note that I put in a lot of details that I wouldn't put in usually.

First I show that $S=\cup_{\alpha\in T}A_\alpha$ by double inclusion.
Take some point $x$ contained in $S$ (i.e. $x$ is a real number). Clearly(*) there exists some rational number $\alpha\in T$ such that $\alpha\leq x$. Now by definition of $A_\alpha$ we have that $x\in A_\alpha$. Note that $A_\alpha$ is contained in $\cup_{\alpha\in T}A_\alpha$ by definiton of the union. Since $x$ was an arbitrary point of $S$, we have the inclusion $S\subseteq \cup_{\alpha\in T}A_\alpha$.
The reverse inclusion is easier to write: the sets $A_\alpha$ are all sets of real numbers; therefore their union is also a set of real numbers: $\cup_{\alpha\in T}A_\alpha\subseteq S$.
Since we have $S\subseteq \cup_{\alpha\in T}A_\alpha\subseteq S$, we must have equality, which proves the claim "by double inclusion".

(*) You can actually prove this (exercise) using the Archimedean property of the real numbers if I recall correctly.

Second I show that $\emptyset=\cap_{\alpha\in T}A_\alpha$. Just for fun let's do it by contradiction: suppose on the contrary that there actually is a point $x\in\cap_{\alpha\in T}A_\alpha$. This means exactly that $x$ is greater than all $\alpha\in T$, i.e. $x$ is a real number bigger than any rational number. This is intuitively impossible, of course. Formally it's again because of the Archimedean property. Here we go. Clearly $x>0$. Then $1/x>0$, so there exists an integer $n$ such that $1/x>1/n>0$. Now we get $x<n$, but $n$ is a rational number (every integer is a rational number), so $x\notin A_n$, which is a contradiction with the fact that $x\in\cap_{\alpha\in T}A_\alpha$. This proves that there could be no element in the intersection (because such an element would have contradicting properties), so that it is the empty set.

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your reply and your detail explanation! I appreciate your consideration :) Good luck to you, too!